# Error using sql server sequence with Hibernate 5.0.3

Tags: hibernate, sequence

This is the error. The 'SQ_USERS' is the sequence created in a sql server database.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.SQ_USERS'.

This is the entity that is used to get the sequence...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER", schema="dbo", sequenceName = "SQ_USERS", allocationSize = 20)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
}
```

The sql that is generated is "select next_val as id_val from dbo.SQ_USERS with (updlock, rowlock)", but if i try this in sql server management studio, i get the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.SQ_USERS'."

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue to the problem. I was using the wrong hibernate dialect. When I changed the dialect to "SQLServer2008Dialect" it worked correctly.

Comment: I was using :  
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect 

It works with :
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `schema` and `catalog` to your `@Table` annotation and see if the error is fixed:

Something like this:

```
@Table(name="USERS", catalog="<your database name>", schema="dbo")
```

Answer (score 0):

If Hibernate dialect is specified as `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`, then the SQL generated to obtain a sequence's next value is:

```
select next_val from my_sql_server_sequence with (updlock, rowlock);
```

which fails with an error: `[S0002][208] Invalid object name 'my_sql_server_sequence'`.

If Hibernate dialect is specified as `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect`, then the SQL generated to obtain a sequence's next value is:

```
select next value for my_sql_server_sequence;
```

This works with Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and Hibernate 5.4.23.